# Node.js app without going through an Apache Proxy

Tags: apache, ubuntu, node-js

I currently have my server set up to use an Apache proxy all the data from the domain "territory.cf" to my Socket.io Node.JS server. But, this system is very slow and the game I am running can't run at its peak performance with the proxy in the way. How should I write my Apache config (or Node.JS if needed) so any requests going to territory.cf go directly to my Node.JS server running on port 25500? I cannot do redirects or use another IP address.

Comment: ive reworded the question, what needs to be made "less broad"